# WordPress SSO with MemberPress

Tags: authentication, membership

I've built an app using React. To authenticate users I am using a custom database with Auth0.

My client is using https://memberpress.com/ to handle subscriptions for multiple things, the app, a forum, and courses.

SSO is the clear answer here. The only problem I am facing is that https://auth0.com/wordpress creates its own login form. This conflicts with the form created by MemberPress.

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to have MemberPress add a user to the WP_Users table then send that user to the central Auth0 database?